# How to fix PermissionError when doing `ls` in ipython?

Tags: python, linux, python-2.7, ipython

When I run `ipython` (version 5.4.1) with `python` 2.7 (2.7.12) and do an `ls` I get an PermissionError:

```
$ ipython 
Python 2.7.12 (default, Dec  4 2017, 14:50:18) 
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

IPython 5.4.1 -- An enhanced Interactive Python.
?         -> Introduction and overview of IPython's features.
%quickref -> Quick reference.
help      -> Python's own help system.
object?   -> Details about 'object', use 'object??' for extra details.

In [1]: ls
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
OSError                                   Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-e6d7425bc79f> in <module>()
----> 1 get_ipython().magic(u'ls ')

/home/adietz/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.pyc in magic(self, arg_s)
   2158         magic_name, _, magic_arg_s = arg_s.partition(' ')
   2159         magic_name = magic_name.lstrip(prefilter.ESC_MAGIC)
-> 2160         return self.run_line_magic(magic_name, magic_arg_s)
   2161 
   2162     #-------------------------------------------------------------------------

/home/adietz/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.pyc in run_line_magic(self, magic_name, line)
   2079                 kwargs['local_ns'] = sys._getframe(stack_depth).f_locals
   2080             with self.builtin_trap:
-> 2081                 result = fn(*args,**kwargs)
   2082             return result
   2083 

/home/adietz/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/core/alias.pyc in __call__(self, rest)
    185             cmd = '%s %s' % (cmd % tuple(args[:nargs]),' '.join(args[nargs:]))
    186 
--> 187         self.shell.system(cmd)
    188 
    189 #-----------------------------------------------------------------------------

/home/adietz/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.pyc in system_raw(self, cmd)
   2247             try:
   2248                 # Use env shell instead of default /bin/sh
-> 2249                 ec = subprocess.call(cmd, shell=True, executable=executable)
   2250             except KeyboardInterrupt:
   2251                 # intercept control-C; a long traceback is not useful here

/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.pyc in call(*popenargs, **kwargs)
    521     retcode = call(["ls", "-l"])
    522     """
--> 523     return Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs).wait()
    524 
    525 

/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.pyc in __init__(self, args, bufsize, executable, stdin, stdout, stderr, preexec_fn, close_fds, shell, cwd, env, universal_newlines, startupinfo, creationflags)
    709                                 p2cread, p2cwrite,
    710                                 c2pread, c2pwrite,
--> 711                                 errread, errwrite)
    712         except Exception:
    713             # Preserve original exception in case os.close raises.

/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.pyc in _execute_child(self, args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds, cwd, env, universal_newlines, startupinfo, creationflags, shell, to_close, p2cread, p2cwrite, c2pread, c2pwrite, errread, errwrite)
   1341                         raise
   1342                 child_exception = pickle.loads(data)
-> 1343                 raise child_exception
   1344 
   1345 

OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied
```

I removed and re-installed `ipython` without success.

When I do a `glob("*")`, however, it works as expected and I get the content of the current directory.

Any ideas how I can fix this issue? Or how to find out the cause?

**Addendum**

After some experimentation I found the offending line was the `subprocess.call` function, and I could reproduce the error by running

```
subprocess.call('ls', shell=True, executable=os.environ.get('SHELL', None))
```

Furthermore, the last part evaluates to an empty string:

```
In [7]: os.environ.get('SHELL', None)
Out[7]: ''
```

which seem to be the offending part. Without it it runs fine

```
In [8]: subprocess.call('ls', shell=True)
adietz  Desktop  Documents  Downloads  examples.desktop  Music  opt  Pictures  Private  Projects  Public  Templates  Videos  Work
Out[8]: 0
```

Comment: Could you try to manually execute `ls -l` in the same directory using the same user?

Comment: A `ls -l` as the same user works just fine on the shell in the exact folder I started the `ipython` shell...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some unknown reasons the user's preferred shell command, specified in the environment variable `SHELL`, was not defined. The usual place where this is defined is the file `/etc/passwd' (see [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EnvironmentVariables)).

So setting this variable by hand removes the above issue:

```
$ export SHELL=/bin/bash
$ ipython
Python 2.7.12 (default, Dec  4 2017, 14:50:18) 
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

IPython 5.4.1 -- An enhanced Interactive Python.
?         -> Introduction and overview of IPython's features.
%quickref -> Quick reference.
help      -> Python's own help system.
object?   -> Details about 'object', use 'object??' for extra details.

In [1]: ls
adietz@  Desktop/  Documents/  Downloads/  examples.desktop  Music/  opt/  Pictures/  Private/  Projects/  Public/  Templates/  Videos/  Work/
```